# Remove the Reminder feature from calendar

Tags: google-calendar

Awhile back my phone asked me if I wanted to turn on the Reminder feature on my Google Calendar app. I answered Yes. Now I'd like to go back and choose No. How can I get rid of the Reminder feature from my Android Calendar app?

What I don't like about it is that

1. It adds an extra click when creating an appointment
2. Unlike an appointment, it doesn't appear at calendar.google.com